# Change view alpha after ripple affect in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to display a ripple affect after click on a view and also change it alpha after click on it.
However, the ripple effect only work well if alpha change from 0.5->1, when alpha change from 1->0.5, the ripple effect don't display fully.

```
fun Greeting2(name: String) {
    val isProcessing = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(36.dp)
            .alpha(if (isProcessing.value) 0.5f else 1f)
            .clickable(
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                indication = rememberRipple(bounded = false),
            ) {
                isProcessing.value = !isProcessing.value
            }
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now),
            contentDescription = "",
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(80.dp)
                .height(80.dp)
        )
        Text(text = "Hello $name!")
    }
}
```

Here is the demo. Any way to achieve both alpha and ripple effect together?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it might be because of the mechanism how the ripple is displayed internally. Maybe it's a sort of clash between the recompositions occuring because of both the changing alpha and the propagating ripple. To fix that, you can just wrap your column in another composable, like so.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Greeting2() {
    val name = "Android!" // I used preview so had to remove the parameter
    var isProcessing by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val alpha by animateFloatAsState(targetValue = if (isProcessing) 0.5f else 1f, animationSpec = keyframes { durationMillis = 1 })
    Box(
        Modifier
            .alpha(alpha)
    ){
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(36.dp)
                .clickable(
                    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                    indication = rememberRipple(bounded = false),
                ) {
                    isProcessing = !isProcessing
                }
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
                contentDescription = "",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(80.dp)
                    .height(80.dp)
            )
            Text(text = "Hello $name!")
        }
    }
}
```

I might have made some modifications but you get the idea. Also, I wrapped in a Box instead of a Surface since it defaults to a background.

Comment: nice idea to go through this problem. I will try to apply it

Comment: I am following your idea but I change a little bit. Instead moving alpha to the `Box`, I move click listener to the `Box`. Then the ripple effect color will not affected by changing alpha.

Comment: Hm. Makes sense.